# パッケージ名の異なるデバッグビルドのAPKが一方だけしかインストールできない

Tags: monaca

monacaで複数プロジェクト開発しています。

Android用にデバッグビルドで作成したAPK（パッケージ名は異なります。）を同じ端末にインストールしようとしたのですが、片方のみしかできません。

同様の現象になった事がある方、回避方法ご存知の方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか？

パッケージ名を変えればインストールできるような回答は見つけたのですが、解決に至るものではなく質問いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

デバッガの制約によるものだと思います。

デバッグビルドのパッケージが複数インストールされていた場合、デバッガは複数のパッケージのデバッグに対処しないといけなくなります。
しかし、普通のデバッガは１つのプログラム（パッケージ）のデバッグにしか対応できません。
そこで、デバッグビルドのパッケージを１つに制限しているのだと思います。(デバッグビルドはdummyの署名になっているので、区別がつきます）

２つのパッケージのデバッグがしたければ、以下の１）、２）を繰り返せば良いのです。
１)一方のパッケージ(a)をリリースビルドして、もう一方のパッケージ(b)のデバッグビルドと共にインストールして、デバッグビルドしたパッケージ(b)の動作確認・デバッグをする。
２)それが終わったら、デバッグビルドしたパッケージ(b)をリリースビルドして、先にリリースビルドしていたパッケージ(a)をデバッグビルド。この２つのインストールして、デバッグビルドしたパッケージ(a)の動作確認・デバッグをする。